# Applying operations on Scheme (R5RS) with a condition

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

I'm trying to create a Scheme program (Language R5RS) which applies an operation to a set of lists, depending on how big a number is on a list.

So the function looks like

```
(apply-function f g)
```

The condition is, if f(a b) where a < 5, then apply operation f(a b).

But if a is equal or greater than 5, apply g(a b). (The second operation)

This sounds confusing but a visual example should clear it up: So, an example would be

```
((apply-function '* '+) '((2 3) (8 6)))
```

Would return:

```
'(6 14)
```

Another example would be

```
((apply-function '* '+) '((5 7) (2 3) (3 3))
```

Returns

```
'(12 6 9)
```

I've tackled operations on Scheme before, but the condition part is throwing me off and I'm not sure where to start. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Version 1***: If you use procedures `+` and `*` instead of symbols `'+`   and `'*`:

```
#lang r5rs

(define apply-function
  (lambda (f g)
    (lambda (lop)
      (map (lambda (p)
             (if (< (car p) 5)
                  (f (car p) (cadr p))
                  (g (car p) (cadr p))))
           lop))))

(display ((apply-function * +) '((2 3) (8 6))))
(newline) 
(display ((apply-function * +) '((5 7) (2 3) (3 3))))
```

***Version 2***: You can make an association list matching symbols to procedures

```
#lang r5rs

(define proc-list `((* . ,*) (+ . ,+)))

(define (get-proc s)
  (let ((p (assq s proc-list)))
    (if p (cdr p) s)))


(define apply-function
  (lambda (f g)
    (lambda (lop)
      (map (lambda (p) 
             (if (< (car p) 5)
                 ((get-proc f) (car p) (cadr p))
                 ((get-proc g) (car p) (cadr p))))
           lop))))

(display ((apply-function '* '+) '((2 3) (8 6))))
(newline) 
(display ((apply-function '* '+) '((5 7) (2 3) (3 3))))
```

***Version 3***: Uses eval

```
#lang r5rs

(define (my-eval e)
  (eval e (scheme-report-environment 5)))

(define apply-function
  (lambda (f g)
    (lambda (lop)
      (map (lambda (p) (if (< (car p) 5)
                           (my-eval (list f (car p) (cadr p)))
                           (my-eval (list g (car p) (cadr p)))))
           lop))))

(display ((apply-function '* '+) '((2 3) (8 6))))
(newline) 
(display ((apply-function '* '+) '((5 7) (2 3) (3 3))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the procedureswere given as `*` and `+`.

Then the operation on one such sub-list would look like

```
(lambda (e) (if (< (car e) 5) 
                (* (car e) (cadr e))
                (+ (car e) (cadr e)))
```

Abstract the given procedures:

```
(define (apply-once f g)
        (lambda (e)
              (if (< (car e) 5) 
                  (f (car e) (cadr e))
                  (g (car e) (cadr e)))))
```

Now you can transform a list with `*` and `+`:

```
(lambda (ls) (map (apply-once * +) ls))
```

And abstract the procedures again:

```
(define (apply-function f g) 
        (lambda (ls) (map (apply-once f g) ls)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that you don't have to map between function names & functions, then an obvious definition is to use `apply`:

```
(define (apply-function f g)
  (lambda (l)
    (map (lambda (e)
           (apply (if (< (car e) 5) f g) e))
         l)))
```